# how do I unset the choice of "Use a Dockerfile or build using the .NET SDK (Use .NET SDK)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When first starting a dynamic debug session with C# in VS Code with the C# dev kit -- as per this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-netcore#_net-sdk-vs-dockerfile-build

If I choose "Use .NET SDK" -- that becomes sticky. In other words, I cannot switch to "User a Dockerfile" --

How can I unset this choice which is seemingly stored in some magical workspace file...

I cannot find a method to unset this anywhere. launch.json is NOT created so this choice is persisted somewhere -- but where.